# R - delete records from data frame

Tags: r

I have a file with 120k records and the key is the username. I want to delete records for some username.
Delete all records for username in "ABC","dd","EEE" etc.
I am using R language

Comment: You can use `subset(df1, !username %in% c("ABC", "dd", "EEE"))`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this.

```
df1[!(df1$username %in% c("ABC","dd","EEE")),]
```

Answer (score -1):

df1[!(df1$username %in% c("ABC","dd","EEE")),]

Let me know if its still not working.

~Ashish

Comment: `!=` is bad for this, e.g., `1:3 != 3:1`

Comment: Thanks Gregor, my bad !